# Unable to test Spring Boot REST API by spring-boot-starter-test while same "api" is working for Postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

My intention is to test my Rest API. I have used JWT authentication. I have set `permittAll()`, for my intended URL. The URL is returning value in postman without authentication but the same URL is not working in integration test. It is showing error that :

```
Error message = Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

**Full Stack Trace** :

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /test/test
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json]}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 401
    Error message = Full authentication is required to access this resource
          Headers = {X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], X-Frame-Options=[DENY], Strict-Transport-Security=[max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains], WWW-Authenticate=[Basic realm="Spring"]}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
```

**Test Class**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = ArticleController.class, secure = false)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class EmployeeRestControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private IArticleService articleService;

    @Test
    public void givenEmployees_whenGetEmployees_thenReturnJsonArray()
            throws Exception {
        String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/test";

        mvc.perform(get(url)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)) 
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(url).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();
        System.out.println("Response : " + result.

    }
}//class
```

I have tried with `secure = false`. But the result is same.

**Config Method** :

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception
        {
        httpSecurity
                // we don't need CSRF because our token is invulnerable
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                // don't create session
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                //.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()

                // allow anonymous resource requests
                .antMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/",
                        "/*.html",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js"
                ).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/test/**","/tes","/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        // Custom JWT based security filter
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        // disable page caching
        httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl();
        }
```

**The URL is returning result when I am testing it in Postman, with no authentication.** My question is that then why I am watching the message authentication required.

**source code :**  [GitHub Link](https://github.com/ajharulabedeen/org.gobeshona/tree/master/back_end/org.gobeshona)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a problem with the following line of your test.

```
@WebMvcTest(value = ArticleController.class, secure = false)
```

You need to define the controller which has `/test/test` endpoint. I think the 401 one is coming because it is try to do a 404 and the 404 endpoint is not publicly available.

Comment: If your assumption is true, then why it is working in in Postman?

Answer (score 0):

.antMatchers("*/test/**","/register").permitAll();

Comment: what the difference it makes?

Comment: exclude all files inside test/text